# background shadow between maximum and minimum value MPCharts Android

Tags: android, view, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I need to have the unfilled area to have a custom background colour in my bar graph between the maximum and minimum values only. How can I achieve this? I've looked into the examples but there are no example what so ever.

So, I did the following to set the background color and to enable shadows.
example what so ever.

```
sleep_bar.setDrawBarShadow(true)
set1.barShadowColor = resources.getColor(R.color.gray, null)
```

What Can I do so that my background shadow remains inside the maximum and minimum values only set manually by me?

[image]